# thymeleaf part is not interpreted in js

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I use thymeleaf
In a js function I create a row. Issue is the thymeleaf part is not interpreted so thymeleaf code is still in the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">

    function addRow(tableId, letter){

        var row=`
            <tr>
              <td  data-id="${letter}">${letter}</td>
              <td> <input class="" type="checkbox" name="compression"> </td>
              /*[# sec:authorize="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER')"]*/   
              <td> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt delete"></i> </td>
              /*[/]*/
             </tr>
              `;
         ...
     } 

</script>
```

Look like ` character cause issue with thymeleaf

Answer (score 1):

You should be using inline JavaScript just as you did but with a small difference. Code sample is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">

    /*<![CDATA[*/
    function addRow(tableId, letter){

        var row='
            <tr>
              <td  data-id="' + ${letter} + '">' + ${letter} + '</td>
              <td> <input class="" type="checkbox" name="compression"> </td>' + 
              /*[# sec:authorize="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER')"]*/   
              '<td> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt delete"></i> </td>' + 
              /*[/]*/
             '</tr>';
         ...
     } 

</script>
```

Please note the ***CDATA*** begin and end markings.